# XQuery with dynamic XPath from XML Sql Server Column

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath, xquery-sql

I have a **log** table has xml column which contains log contents

There is also table called **logType** which is the type of log

I need to create query descripes the xml contents as readable string

I added a column with name logXPath to logtype table

and i created the following query

```
SELECT   contents.value(LogXPath, 'nvarchar(max)')
FROM    dbo.Log 
        JOIN dbo.LogType ON dbo.Log.logTypeID = dbo.LogType.logTypeID
```

and I got the following error

**The argument 1 of the XML data type method "value" must be a string literal**

and I searched for a way to do this with no results!!

**Is there any do dynamic xpath in Sql Server XML Column?**

**Edit**

for example assume the following schema and data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[logType]
    (
      [logTypeID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [logTypeName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL ,
      [xPath] [nvarchar](MAX) NOT NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_logType] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [logTypeID] ASC )
    )

GO
INSERT  [dbo].[logType]
        ( [logTypeID] ,
          [logTypeName] ,
          [xPath]
        )
VALUES  ( 1 ,
          N'Patient Data' ,
          N'(/Patient/PatientName)[1]'
        )
INSERT  [dbo].[logType]
        ( [logTypeID] ,
          [logTypeName] ,
          [xPath]
        )
VALUES  ( 2 ,
          N'Clinic Data' ,
          N'(/Clinic/ClinicName)[1]'
        )
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[log]    Script Date: 02/04/2015 13:58:47 ******/
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[log]
    (
      [logID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [logTypeID] [int] NOT NULL ,
      [Contents] [xml] NULL ,
      CONSTRAINT [PK_log] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [logID] ASC )
    )
GO
INSERT  [dbo].[log]
        ( [logID] ,
          [logTypeID] ,
          [Contents]
        )
VALUES  ( 1 ,
          1 ,
          N'<Patient><PatientID>1</PatientID><PatientName>john</PatientName></Patient>'
        )
INSERT  [dbo].[log]
        ( [logID] ,
          [logTypeID] ,
          [Contents]
        )
VALUES  ( 2 ,
          2 ,
          N'<Clinic><ClinicID>1</ClinicID><ClinicName>Clinic 1</ClinicName></Clinic>'
        )
```

When I make query like the following ,it gives me the error

```
SELECT  logTypeName ,
        [Contents].value(dbo.logType.xPath, 'nvarchar(max)') AS data
FROM    dbo.[log]
        JOIN dbo.logType ON dbo.[log].logTypeID = dbo.logType.logTypeID
```

Comment: How about executing the whole `SELECT` statement as dynamic SQL?

Comment: the problem is my xpath can't be a variable it stored in sql column and has different value for each logtype and the xml structure is different for each logtype

so if I want to use dynamic sql i have to create a query for each logtype  but i need to get then in one query

Comment: please give sample data. so we check.

Comment: Done, I wrote a full example

Answer (score 1):

You can build a query dynamically using the table `LogType`.

```sql
declare @SQL nvarchar(max);

set @SQL = 'select case L.logTypeID'+
            (
            select ' when '+cast(LT.logTypeID as varchar(11))+
                     ' then L.Contents.value('''+LT.xPath+''', ''nvarchar(max)'')'
            from LogType as LT
            for xml path('')
            )+' end as Name from dbo.[Log] as L;';

exec (@SQL);
```

It will give you a query that looks like this:

```sql
select case L.logTypeID 
         when 1 then L.Contents.value('(/Patient/PatientName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
         when 2 then L.Contents.value('(/Clinic/ClinicName)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') 
       end as Name 
from dbo.[Log] as L;
```

Comment: good solution for small numbers of types, but logtype it self contains about 1000+ record

Comment: @user897645 Yes, that could be a problem. I reached the limit on my computer at 675 different types. After that SQL Server could not create a query plan.

Comment: @user897645 Is the shape of the xPath always the same? One root and get the first value of a child node to root?

Comment: For the shapes in your sample you can just use `select L.Contents.value('(/*/*)[2]', 'nvarchar(max)')
from dbo.[log] as L;`

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this has been here a while (a year), but this might be helpful...

A VERY helpful TABLE function: http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/28/posts/10495/xquery-lab-58-select-from-xml.aspx

Using that function, you can get the values you're after something like this:

```
Select l.Contents, t.XPath, x.Value
  From [log] l With (NoLock)
 Inner Join [LogType] t With (NoLock)
         on t.LogTypeID=l.LogTypeID
 CROSS APPLY XMLTable(l.Contents) AS x
 Where REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(t.XPath,'[1]',''),'(',''),')','')=REPLACE('/'+x.XPath,'[1]','')
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does not allow replacing entire XPath expression with a variable, but you can use `sql:variable` and `sql:column` extensions **inside** the expression (I can't say how exactly without seeing your xml structure and what information you want to query from XML column).

Or, as mentioned above, you can use dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @xpath NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @xpath = ... //Calculate xpath expression here

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'SELECT contents.value(''' + @xpath + ''', ''NVARCHAR(MAX)''
             FROM dbo.Log 
             JOIN dbo.LogType ON dbo.Log.logTypeID = dbo.LogType.logTypeID';

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: the problem is my xpath can't be a variable 
it stored in sql column and has different value for each logtype
and the xml structure is different  for each logtype